# OneToMany or ManyToMany Mappring in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, one-to-many

I am trying to create 2 entity classes with OneTOMany option. Below is my table Structure.

```
|             |      |                  |
|   EVENTS    |      |   PARTICIPANT    |
|_____________|      |__________________|
|             |      |                  |
| *EVENT_ID   |  --> | *EVENT_ID        |
|  EVENT_DATE |      | *EMAIL           |
|  TITLE      |      |  PARTICIPANT_NAME|
|_____________|      |__________________|
```

Event Id will be auto generated and participants related to an event should be saved along with the event details. Below are my entity classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENTS")
public class Event{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "event_id")
   private Integer eventId;

   @column(name = "event_date")
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date eventDate;
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
   private List<Participant> participantList;
   //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PARTICIPANT")
public class Participant{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "event_id")
   private Integer eventId;

   @Id
   @column(name = "email")
   private String email;

   @Column(name = "participant_name")
   private String participantName;
   //getters and setters
}
```

While creating a new EVENT I am setting the Participants list and trying to save. If I modify a saved event by changing the date and remove some participants and add new participants I want to update the participants table without any extra effort save call. Which one would be the correct annotation to be used. I am using `Hibernate 4.3.10` version.
**NOTE** I don't want to create a new Mapping table as I don't have the whole Participants list. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> If I modify a saved event by changing the date and remove some
>   participants and add new participants I want to update the
>   participants table without any extra effort save call.

You should choose necessary cascade type and orphan removal option in your `Event` class (whether to apply the remove operation to entities that have been removed from the relationship and to cascade the remove operation to those entities):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "event", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Participant> participantList;
```

Also, I would suggest to have separate primary key (id) for `Participant`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

And if you decide to implement your solution with `OneToMany` - `ManyToOne` relationship add to `Participant`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="event_id")
Event event;
```

The solution above has drawback - one participant can be related with just one event. You should use `@ManyToMany` relationship if the same participant can attend to more than 1 event.